# Why is WebRTC encrypted?

Tags: webrtc

I am interested in experimenting with WebRTC data streams as a method of low-latency communication between peers in multiplayer games in the browser, but have read that WebRTC is always encrypted. From http://webrtc-security.github.io/

> Encryption is a mandatory feature of WebRTC, and is enforced on all components, including signaling mechanisms. Resultantly, all media streams sent over WebRTC are securely encrypted, enacted through standardised and well-known encryption protocols. The encryption protocol used depends on the channel type; data streams are encrypted using Datagram Transport Layer Security (DTLS) and media streams are encrypted using Secure Real-time Transport Protocol (SRTP).

It seems odd to me to have encryption so tightly coupled in this way. I can think of contexts where mandatory encryption is a hindrance, like multiplayer gaming where data transferred is non-sensitive and having to encrypt/decrypt data is unnecessary overhead, however small. For comparison, WebSockets communication is encrypted further down the stack by TLS if present, but the option of communicating over plain TCP is available as well. Am I misunderstanding this or is there a reason why it was decided that all WebRTC communication must be encrypted?

Comment: Even when the data is not sensitive, encryption is a good thing. It makes it so people can't mess with your data when it's between your client and server (or between two clients in the case of webrtc)

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC is defining new realm for browsers which was not primarily intended. IMO Accessing camera/microphone rises enough resistance to use the technology solely so mandatory encryption gonna ease it.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason as HTTPS communication is encrypted, they're trying to avoid a middle man to get advantage of the peer to peer communication